# contains a skill of type \'Microsoft.Skills.Text.AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill\' which is not supported in this API version

Tags: azure, openai-api, azure-cognitive-search, azure-openai, openaiembeddings

when using AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill in azure AI search as per:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-azure-openai-embedding
I am getting the following error:

`contains a skill of type \'Microsoft.Skills.Text.AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill\' which is not supported in this API version.`

I am trying to create a skillset and get the data embedded using AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-azure-openai-embedding), `Azure OpenAI Embedding Skill` feature is supported in API version **2023-10-01-Preview**.

To fix the issue, use the updated API version.

Below is sample python code snippet:

```py
import json
import requests

endpoint = 'https://<Search_Name>.search.windows.net/'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'api-key': ''}
params = {
    'api-version': '2023-10-01-Preview' #Supported Version
}
skillset_payload = {
    "name": skillset_name,
    "description":
    "Embedding Skill",
    "skills":
    [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill",
            "resourceUri": "https://<OpenAI_Name>.openai.azure.com/",
            "apiKey": "",
            "deploymentId": "testada",
            "name": "embedding",
            "description": "test",
            "inputs": [
                {
                "name": "text",
                "source":"/document/content"
                
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                "name": "embedding",
                "targetName": "embedding"
    }
  ]
}   
    ]
}

r = requests.put(endpoint + "/skillsets/" + skillset_name,
                 data=json.dumps(skillset_payload), headers=headers, params=params)
print(r.status_code)
```

With above code, I was able to create Azure OpenAI Embedding skillset.
[image]